# Android studio mock build variant - How to include mock classes?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to set up testing in my app similar to the [Android Testing Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0), and I created a mock build variant in app/build.gradle to do it:

```
productFlavors {
    mock {

    }
    prod {

    }
}
```

I then set the build variant to mockDebug, created a mock folder in the src/ directory, and then created a mock activity (ThreePaneMockActivity) and other classes (ThreePaneMockView, ThreePaneMockPresenter) in the mock folder. After that, I tried to run the mock activity to start testing a custom view I created (ThreePaneWindow). Upon running the mock activity, the ap crashes with an exception caused by the following problem:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.ThreePaneMockView" on path: DexPathList....

ThreePaneMockView is in the same package as ThreePaneMockActivity, so I'm guessing there is something wrong with my app build.gradle file that isn't building that class file and including it in the app package. Also, Android is looking for "android.view.ThreePaneMockView" instead of in my mock package.

So, what am I doing wrong with my mock build variant? How do I get all the mock classes correctly included in the build?

EDIT: Folder hierarchy:

```
src/
 |
 |---main/
 |     |
 |     |---java/com/wilee8/coyotereader3/threepanewindow/
 |          |
 |          |---ThreePaneWindow.java
 |---mock/
       |
       |---java/com/wilee8/coyotereader3/
            |
            |---ThreePaneMockActivity.java
            |---ThreePaneMockPresenter.java
            |---ThreePaneMockView.java
```

ThreePaneMockView extends LinearLayout, and it's the follwing line in ThreePaneMockActivity that's causing the exception:

```
ThreePaneMockView view = (ThreePaneMockView)
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_three_pane_mock, null);
```

R.layout.view_three_pane_mock was created in the mockDebug variant and has a ThreePaneMockView at the top level.

**AND THERE IT IS**

So typing out this response got me to the answer, it had nothing to do with configuring the build variant. When I was double checking that the tag at the top of R.layout.view_three_pane_mock was  I realized it needed to be . I changed that and it worked-ish - it still crashed, but new errors.

Comment: Post also your folder and file hierarchy.